# How can i send multiple return to single function call over time

Tags: c#, .net, function, return

How can i send multiple return to single function call over time in C#

Lets consider

```
public int myFunction(){

// 1st return willbe.. call received

//2nd return will be processing your request

//3rd return will be processed 

}
```

i.e. return 3 different status over the time

Comment: just use yield : examples http://www.dotnetperls.com/yield

Comment: Do you want to return multiple objects from the method  and you want to return all three object at same call ?

Comment: Thanks I will try above method

Comment: In C# !!, that is impossible. you only return one value, but you can for example use yield or simply use multiple functions and call them when needed

Answer (score 1):

If your are looking for your main method to return something like progress then you can use `BackgroundWorker` to report progress of the main function like below:

```
BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

_worker.DoWork += myFunction;
_worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
_worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_worker.RunWorkerAsync();


void myFunction(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     _worker.ReportProgress(10);
     _worker.ReportProgress(30);
     _worker.ReportProgress(50);
}
```

//This funtion will be called to report progress.

```
void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
     int returnvalue = e.ProgressPercentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't return more than once from a single method, but you could declare events in your class and then suscribe to those events in your calling class

```
MyClass{
  event OnSomething1;
  event OnSomething2;

 public DoSomething(){
   OnSomething1();
   //Other code
   OnSomething2();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that syntax is not available in C# but you can select another approach.

you can define an "Status" property or field out of the method to get and set status of task.
or you can return several result in IEnumerable type by yield keyword that not very useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

To differ the return value from a method based on the time it has been called, you could implement a state machine with a private member which indicates in which *state* your object is.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _currentState = 0;

    public int myFunction()
    {
        switch (_currentState)
        {
            case 0:
                _currentState = 1;
                return 1; // 1st return willbe.. call received

            case 1:
                _currentState = 2;
                return 2; // 2nd return will be processing your request

            case 2:
                return 3; // 3rd return will be processed 

            default:
                return -1; // not handled
        }
    }
}
```